# Return Oriented Programming Stripped Binaries

Tags: elf, buffer-overflow, memory-corruption

Good morning,

I have a stripped binary, and I have to bypass ASLR and NX. I am fighting since three days to find a solution but I cannot find one. I cannot find the libraries linked to the binary as it is stripped ("not a dynamic object") to build my ROP chain against. Would someone know about it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20497/stack-overflows-defeating-canaries-aslr-dep-nx 
maybe this? also I think this question is more suitable for reverse-engineering exchange or security exchange

Comment: Thanks yes, I guess it was not the best place for my question!